# Transcedental number or not?

Tags: soft-question, irrational-numbers

I need help to classify this number. The solutions to $3^y-y^3=0$ are 3 and 2.47805268....  it is irrational 
But since it is a root for this equation is the number transcedental or not? The original problem comes from $3^y=y^3$ where one sees it is an irrational number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem), if $y$ is an algebraic irrational then $3^y$ is transcendental, but $y^3$ is algebraic, therefore they can't be equal.